# Дискретные переменные

Tags: c++, терминология

Что подразумевается под дискретными переменными в С++

С [сайта microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/0e5kx78b.aspx):

> Поскольку статические данные-члены являются дискретными переменными,
>   общими для всех объектов класса, их необходимо определять и
>   инициализировать за пределами объявления класса.

Comment: Пример - enum. Вообще переменные, которые принимают только ряд определенных значений.

Comment: Скорее всего, этот вопрос не относится к c++, так как в нем нет никаких *дискретных переменных*. Приведите контекст, откуда вы взяли это понятие. @demonplus При чем тут enum? Енумераторы могут принимать все значения, которые может принимать их базовый тип, поэтому они не более дискретны, чем обычные целые типы.

Comment: Это похоже на сложности перевода. Вместо *дискретные* я бы написал *отдельные*, так как статические поля класса существуют независимо т.е. отделены от объектов этого класса.

Comment: К С++ это вообще не относится. Просто переменные бывают в принципе дискретные и непрерывные

Comment: В данной цитате вообще имеется в виду другое

Comment: @demonplus в пк, пожалуй, все переменные дискретные, т.к. между любыми компьютерными А и B (А<B) всегда можно записать на бумаге такое число С для которого будет А<C<B, т.к. дробное число представлено конечной мантисой, а целые числа уже дискретны с шагом 1. В связи с этим есть понятие "потеря точности". Дробные числа поэтому похожи на *непрерывные* но фактически в ПК они *дискретные*.

Comment: @nick_n_a строго говоря, да. Поэтому об этом говорить вообще смысла нет :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как уже заметил в [комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/809206/%D0%94%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5#comment1281964_809206) @VTT здесь имеют место быть сложности перевода. В оригинале фраза [звучит так](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/0e5kx78b.aspx):

> Because static class data members are discrete variables shared by all objects of the class, they must be defined and initialized outside the class declaration.

Т.е. акцент должен быть сделан именно на том, что статические члены-данные класса являются **отдельными** (от экземпляра класса) переменными, существующими в единственном виде для всех объектов класса.